# How to solve such expression of random variables?

Tags: random-variables

I have three random variables $ g, h,f$ and one constant $\alpha$. I know that the square of absolute value of product of $\alpha, g, f$ i.e., $|\alpha*g*f|^{2}$ can be expressed as $\alpha^2$ $|g*f|$. So how the expression $|h+\alpha*g*f|^{2}$ can be simplified. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes....here these random variables are complex Gaussian.

Comment: Your question is one on algebra of complex numbers. This has nothing to do with random variables.

Comment: Ok....but how to proceed....